# how do i get this cookie to expire after 14 days from today(which will be whenever the user generates)

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
 function myCookieCreator(){
 document.cookie="myCoookie=isTrueSet; expires=Thu, 30 Mar 2017 
 12:00:00 UTC";
 }
```

Can I make it expire 14 days from the date of creation within the same line of code? This is how I am creating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
By Default, the cookie deleted when the browser is closed but its expiry date can be set to some other date like-:
```

## steps

Get the current date.
Add 14 days.
and place new varible in place of expire.

```
var newDate = new Date();
var dateAdd = newDate.setDate(today.getUTCDate()+14);
document.cookie = "expires=+dateAdd+";
```

Comment: function flashStore(){
       var newDate = new Date();
var dateAdd = newDate.setDate(today.getUTCDate()+14);
document.cookie = "expires=+dateAdd+";
document.cookie="flashstore=isTrueSet; expires=Thu, 30 Mar 2017 12:00:00 UTC";
 }'